# Definition of the Jacquet Module

Tags: representation-theory, definition

My source on this is "The Local Langlands for GL(2)" by Bushnell and Henniart. Let $G=GL_2(F)$, where $F$ is a non-Archimedean local field. Let $B$ be the standard Borel subgroup of $G$, $N$ the unipotent radical of $B$ and $T$ the standard split maximal torus in $G$.

The book says the following:
Let $(\pi, V)$ be a smooth representation of $G$. Define $V(N)$ to be the subspace of $V$ spanned by vectors of the form $v-\pi_x(v)$ where $v \in V$ and $x \in N$. The space $V_N=V/V(N)$ inherits a representation $\pi_N$ of $T=B/N$, which is smooth. We call $(\pi_N,V_N)$ the Jacquet module of $(\pi,V)$ at $N$.

If $V(N)$ was $T$-stable, then after restricting $\pi$ to $T$ we would get a representation of $T$ on the quotient $V_N$. However since this isn't the case, I don't see how $\pi_N$ comes about. Can someone give some insight of how $\pi_N$ is obtained.

Comment: It actually seems to me that $V(N)$ is $T$-stable since $\pi_t(v - \pi_x(v)) = \pi_t(v) - \pi_{txt^{-1}}(\pi_t(v))$ and $txt^{-1} \in N$.

Comment: Matthias: You are correct, thanks.